# How to get ruby on rails production mount-point included in url_helpers for email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rack

**tl;dnr**: My page links are fine, but links erb-olated into non-page text (email) lack the production app mount-point.

**detail**: My RoR app uses slightly different URLs in dev and production: in dev, the top-level entity is the resource model:

```
http://localhost:3000/ENTITY/1/edit
```

But in production, the app is mounted one level down, so URLS have an extra term:

```
https://server.example.com/APP/ENTITY/1/edit
```

This works fine for most cases: url_helpers like `edit_entity_url` return the URLs as I've shown them. Frankly, I'm not clear exactly how that works; I suppose Phusion Passenger and Rack work it out?

However, when I send email (such as to confirm a password reset), it's not working: `edit_entity_url` never adds the `APP` mount-point. Short of my own conditional logic in ERB, how can I get that "/APP" in there?

Things I've tried:

- Setting `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] to include "/registry" (no effect)
- using `<%= link_to 'Reset', edit_entity_url(...) %>`   (no help)

Version info:

- actionmailer (4.0.2)
- Rails 4.0.2
- ruby 2.1.0p0
- rack (1.5.2)
- passenger (4.0.35)

The Apache "sites-enabled" file that ties things together (and the only place I can find that the "/registry" token is defined):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    Alias /registry /app01/capapp/registry/current/public
    <Location /registry>
        PassengerBaseURI /registry
        PassengerAppRoot /app01/capapp/registry/current
    </Location>
    <Directory /app01/capapp/registry/current/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The Rails `config/environments/production.rb` file.

```
Registration::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "server.example.com"
end

Registration::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
:email => {
  :email_prefix => "[Registration]",
  :sender_address => %{"Admin" <XXX@example.com>},
  :exception_recipients => %w{XXX@example.com}
}
```

View for the email (`app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb`):

```
To reset your password click the URL below.  

<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.password_reset_token) %>

If you did not request your password to be reset please ignore this email 
and your password will stay as it is.
```

Yes, it's odd to base the URL on the reset_token not the user_id, but it's handled in the controller. Structure based on [Railscast #274](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password)

Comment: Now that I've posted, the StackOverflow "similar questions" gremlin points out this very similar, 9-month-old, unanswered question: [RackEnv not respected when using route helpers from model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005565/rackenv-not-respected-when-using-route-helpers-from-model?rq=1)

Comment: Various searchable discussion suggest creating a virtual host, rather than munging the URL, but this involves DNS entries, which are beyond my immediate scope.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a **disgusting** hack, but I "solved" this by manual intervention. In `app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb`, I now say:

```
To reset your password click the URL below.  

<%  url = root_url.chomp('/') %>
<%  url += "/registry" if Rails.env.production? %>
<%= url + edit_password_reset_path(@user.password_reset_token) %>
```

Still interested if anyone has a better idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the :script_name parameter to url_for (or other methods based on url_for) to set the mount point.   I use

```
url_for( :only_path => false,
:host => some.host,
:script_name => Rails.application.config.relative_url_root
...
```

and set config.relative_url_root = '/your-mount-point' in the config.

More details about it here:
[how-to-get-ruby-on-rails-production-mount-point-included-in-url-helpers-for-email](http://zergsoft.blogspot.jp/2014/04/using-non-root-mount-point-with-rails-3.html)